# dealing 2 arrays to 1 array in angular ngrx store?

Tags: arrays, angular, ngrx-store

I have two arrays a=[a,b,c] and b =[x,y,z] saved in the ngrx store as store=[a,b,c,x,y,z]. my problem is I have to delete the element in store array based on the index number only.

example: if I have to delete 'y' i'm getting an index number of y i.e: 2 but the index in store array has b.

please I need help in this scenario.

Comment: First question, why you have 1 array in store instad of 2?

you need to recreate the 2 array in the reducer, remove the 'y' element from the correct array (pass a param in the reducer?) and then recreate the array for set in the store.

Comment: Even though if i create a 2nd array in the reducer the only argument I can pass is index number. (problem with different teams (sic) )

Comment: No, in the action you can pass anything... letter, index, object

Comment: That's what i have specified that I'm getting the wrong index number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would fetch the value of the initial array and fetch the index through the value in the array store to delete it.

something like:

```
let value = b[idx] //idx is the position you get'it
let index = store.indexOf(value);
if (index !== -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Other way is to passing the value directly instead of passing the index, in this case ignore the first line, which I think is easier,
.